# What will happen if I tried to boot into twrp recovery without flashing it (not made for my device)

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, twrp, 8.1-oreo, vivo

As their is no twrp recovery for my device (vivo 1802 mtk device)
I was thinking of booting into twrp recovery not made for my device specifically **Without** flashing it.

To get the job done maybe some backups or flashing using twrp.
But I don’t know what will be the consequences of it……
If anyone got idea or hands on experience on it, I would like to know

Comment: The core of the recovery as well as the main ROM is the Android kernel. If you try to boot a kernel not specifically built for your device, it won't boot at all in most cases due to missing device tree and other reasons.